# A main menu in turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

Can someone please explain to me why the program gives the "Else" response no matter where you click and why it repeats itself till it crashes? I dont have a for loop or while loop there so i dont understand. Could it be the onscreenclick() or listen() functions? also, I'm aware of the issue of part of the menu being off screen. I was planning to fix it after checking how well this works.

```
import turtle

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)

#Creating Menu option buttons
def button(length):
    for i in range(4):
        pen.forward(length)
        pen.left(90)

def column(n, length):
    pen.left(270)
    for i in range(n):
        button(length)
        pen.forward(length)
    pen.penup()
    pen.left(90)
    pen.forward(n * length)
    pen.left(180)
    pen.pendown()

column(5, 100)

#Menu Options
pen.penup()
pen.goto(8, -46)
pen.write("START GAME!", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(6, -145)
pen.write("RULES", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(3, -248)
pen.write("HIGH SCORE", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(4, -343)
pen.write("FAQ", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(3, -450)
pen.write("QUIT GAME", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

#Making options clickable
def btnclick(x,y):
    if x > 0 and x < 101 and y > 0 and y < -101:
        print("Start Game")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif x > 0 and x < 101 and y > 101 and y < -201:
        print("Rules")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif x > 0 and x < 101 and y > 201 and y < -301:
        print("Highscore")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif x > 0 and x < 101 and y > 301 and y < -401:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif x > 0 and x < 101 and y > 401 and y < -501:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif x > 0 and x < 101 and y > 501 and y < -601:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    else:
        print("Click One Of The Options!")
        print(x, y)
        btnclick(x, y)

turtle.onscreenclick(btnclick, 1)
turtle.listen()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program on paper or using a debugger?

Comment: this `y > 501 and y < -601:` is impossible - `y` can't be at the same time bigger then 501 and lower then -601. Maybe you need `or` instead of `and`, Or maybe you have to replace `<` and `>` OR maybe you should remove `-` (minus) in all `if/else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot minus and you have to replace `<` with `>` in

```
y > 0 and y < -101:

y > 101 and y < -201:

y > 201 and y < -301:

y > 301 and y < -401:

y > 401 and y < -501:

y > 501 and y < -601:
```

It should be ie.

```
y < 0 and y > -101

y < -101 and y > -201

y < -201 and y > -301

# etc.
```

or shorter

```
0 > y > -101

-101 > y > -201

-201 > y > -301

# etc.
```

---

**EDIT:** Maybe you should use `>=` in some places because old code doesn't work for `y == -101`, `y == -201`, etc.

```
0 > y >= -101

-101 > y >= -201

-201 > y >= -301

etc.
```

---

Full function

```
def btnclick(x,y):
    if 0 < x < 101 and 0 > y > -101:
        print("Start Game")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif 0 < x < 101 and -101 > y > -201:
        print("Rules")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif 0 < x < 101 and -201 > y > -301:
        print("Highscore")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif 0 < x < 101 and -301 > y > -401:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif 0 < x < 101 and -401 > y > -501:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif 0 < x < 101 and -501 > y > -601:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    else:
        print("Click One Of The Options!")
        print(x, y)
        btnclick(x, y)
```